# Multiple click events fire on a single click GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have a FlexTable and have a click event associated with it. It happens sometimes that events are trigerred multiple times. Sometimes up to 10 times on a single click. I have checked for multiple event handlers but I have only one. As evident from the case that it sometimes run exactly once per click.

Has anyone have any idea about it why it could be happening.

Here is sample snippet, I tried debugging it and found the click handler is fired up multiple times.

```
        private FlexTable flex = new FlexTable(); //it is a global variable
        function A(){
          flex.clear();
          flex.removeAllRows();
          flex.removeAllRows();
          flex.setBorderWidth(2);
          flex.setCellPadding(2);
          flex.setCellSpacing(2);
          flex.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(0, "historyTableHeader");
          flex.setText(0, 0, "ID");
          flex.setText(0, 1, "TIME);
          flex.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
              public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                  //some code which might result into call of function B
              }
       }

      //function A is being called multiple times by say function B
```

Comment: Please add some example code of what you are doing.

You must be doing something wrong, cause this is not normal behaviour and I have never seen this. But without example code I have no idea what could be causing this.

Comment: We need more code than that - you have a field (`flex`) mixed with code that obviously isn't next to that line, and if that block of code runs more than once, you'll get the behavior you describe.

Comment: The problem is that the method that wraps this code is being called multiple times and your addClickHandler is being added multiple times. Are you putting this in a constructor. Add a debug message every time you are calling flex.addClickHandler and you will see it is being called multiple times.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw I have added the code more elaborately.

Comment: @ColinAlworth I have added the code more elaborately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already gave an answer to your question:

```
flex.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
       //some code which might result into call of function B
    }
}
//function A is being called multiple times by say function B
```

In this case the ClickHandler exists multiple times. You could change your code to:

```
private FlexTable flex = new FlexTable(); //it is a global variable
private ClickHandler handler = null;

private void A(){
    flex.clear();
    //
    if(handler == null){
        handler = new ClickHandler(){}...
        flex.addHandler(handler);
    }
```

Better:

```
private FlexTable flex = new FlexTable(); //it is a global variable
private HandlerRegistration handler = null;

private void A(){
    flex.clear();
    //
    if(handler != null){
        handler.removeHandler(); 
    }
    handler = flex.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
       //some code which might result into call of function B
    }
}
```

But I would suggest to add the handler directly after the creation of the FlexTable and only once.

Comment: Also, its possible that when called a second time, that a new handler will need to be attached, so removing the old one (via HandlerRegistration) and replacing it would make more sense.

Comment: @ColinAlworth: I added the HandlerRegistration